# Im new to angularjs - please guide with some solution

Tags: angularjs, session-variables

Im using angular service with a variable and my app.js looks like..,

```
app.service('sessionService', function() {
  var users = [
    name: ' ',
    age: ' ',
    gender: M,
    marStatus: single
  ];
});
```

I have a logout option, how to reset my variable users to its default option?

Comment: It looks like there is problem with your design. This is because you are trying to modify your model in the service. This isn't advisable, hence try to get the data from service to a controller and set the values there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service with http call to your server action.The response will always set the data in a correct way.

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('getUserDetailsService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.getDetails = function() {
  var details = {name:'',age:'',gender:'M'}
        $http.get('Your action url')
        .success(function(data) {
          details.name = data.name;
          details.age = data.age;
          details.gender = data.gender;
        })
        .error(function() {
           //handle error
        });
      return details;
    };

}]);

//Controller
app.controller("userController",function($scope,getUserDetailsService){

$scope.getDetails = function() {
getUserDetailsService.getDetails().then(function(detail) {
            $scope.details = detail;

        }, function(error) {

        });
        }

        $scope.getDetails() //Call whenever you want
});
```

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/ftzyyt0L/3/

Comment: Thanks for your response N.K.. the reason i went for service is too hold some data that has to be accessed across the controllers. service variable 'details' will be updated by most of the controllers. my details variable contains many fields needed by all my controllers. On logout, i am just trying for an option to reset my details variable to their default values